# How Get The Clicked Line Number Android TextView

Tags: android, textview, xamarin

I have a string of text items I want displayed in a textview. If line 3 is clicked I'd like to know that. Is that information passed in an eventarg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yourTextView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            int lineHeight = yourTextView.getLineHeight();
            int clickedLine = (int)(event.getY() / lineHeight);
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

Do some thing like this. Did not evaluated the code but hope this will help. You can also try adding [ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) for each line in the TextView.